# Ruby: How to initialize an active merchant gateway instance with credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

From this http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/ActiveMerchant%2FBilling%2FBase.gateway

I should just initialize an instance of active_merchant using this

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.gateway( gateway_name ).new(
:username => :some_credential 
:password => :some_other_credential
)
```

But I don't know `:username` or `:password` in advance, however they are in the fixtures file https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/test/fixtures.yml here. So how to do this properly?

For an example, in the fixtures.yml file we can see this..

`adyen:
  username: ''
  password: ''
  merchant_account: ''`

Accordingly we can initialize with this..

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.gateway( 'adien' ).new(
username:         => :some_credential 
password:         => :some_other_credential
merchant_account: => some_more_credential
)
```

I need to be able to initialize the gateway instance without hard-coding the `username:`, `password:` and `merchant_account:` parameters in the above example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at environment variables. They let you define variables in a safe palce and refer to them when needed.

Somewhere you would define `PASSWORD=mysecretpassword` and then in the Rails code you refer to it as `ENV["PASSWORD"]`

There are many ways of doing this. Take a look here:

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Comment: I was asking for a way without hardcoding the "username:" and "password:" and "merchant_account:" into the example code, and not the ":some_credential", ":some_other_credential" parts (where your solution would obviously solve). I think I was mistaken picking the term "credentials parameters", so editing now...

Answer (score 0):

The username, password, and merchant_account are instance variables so you need to change them with `instance_variable_set`

```
gateway.instance_variable_set(:@username, :some_username)
gateway.instance_variable_set(:@password, :some_password)
gateway.instance_variable_set(:@merchant_account, :some_merchant_account)
```

Comment: but that can only be true for the adien example.. what to do in case the gateway requires just two credentials like @username and @password? What if just requires one credential like @apikey?

Answer (score 0):

I think i can answer my own question. One should pass every different initialization with its own hash..

```
require 'active_merchant'

    settings = {name: 'braintree_blue', merchant_id: 'x', public_key: 'y', private_key: 'z'}
    another_settings = {name: 'trust_commerce', login: 'TestMerchant', password: 'password'}

Gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base::gateway(settings[:name]).new(settings)
Another_Gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base::gateway(another_settings[:name]).new(another_settings)

puts Gateway.options
puts Another_Gateway.options
```

Note that I could pass different options without the need to hardcode any keys, which is what i desired.